# Is it legal to create a 4 second gif from a movie clip?

Tags: copyright

I run a fun page on social media. I want to create gif from movie clips and use it for creative memes, purely for entertainment purpose. Will it come under fair usage if I give credit to the source on my page.

Comment: Creating a 4 second gif from a movie isn’t exactly creative, is it?